# Finding uniform polytopes in 3D versus in 4D

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, polytopes

1. How was the exhaustive uniform polyhedron search (which found the great dirhombicosidodecahedron) conducted?
2. What’s so difficult about doing the same thing but in four dimensions?